# one-of neighbors with [pcolor = blue], why does the with line give me an error? ASK expected input to be an agent or agentset but got NOBODY instead

Tags: netlogo, modeling

Im working on an assignment on netlogo and im making an aquarium.
i need to write code to grow the algae in the aquarium, but i get this error message:

ASK expected input to be an agent or agentset but got NOBODY instead.

second one is my code:

```
to groei_algen
  ask patches [
    if pcolor = green [
      if %omringing = 100 [set pcolor blue] 

      ask one-of neighbors with [pcolor = blue] [
        if random 100 > %omringing [set pcolor green]    
      ]
    ]
  ]

end
```

with %omringing is how many algae there are around the patch
it works without the 'with'

i need to decrease the chance to grow algae when there is more algae around an algae patch.

Comment: Put your code and error directly in the question, please. Copy/paste, don't screenshot.

Comment: There is a huge amount of questions in the `netlogo` section asking about this specific error. Please search "[netlogo] but got nobody" in the search bar.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are getting this error because you did not account for the possibility of a patch not having any neighboring patches with color blue.

A simple way to solve this is to add an additional `if` statement like below:

```
to groei_algen
  ask patches [
    if pcolor = green [
      if %omringing = 100 [set pcolor blue] 

      if any? neighbors with [pcolor = blue] [
        ask one-of neighbors with [pcolor = blue] [
          if random 100 > %omringing [set pcolor green]    
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
end
```